# Working Directory changes when program starts / How to get program files dir

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, makefile

In my c++ program (I'm following the Vulkan helloTriangle guide), when I run the executable, the working directory auto-defaults to /Users/foo, even though my file is in /Users/foo/Desktop/Game/src. I've tried deleting all of the code in the main file (just in case it was a glfw problem), but that didn't fix the issue.

**Edit:** It doesn't default to /Users/foo, when I run the program It shows Game as the folder in Terminal, but then it changes to foo.

I'm currently using very absolute paths, such as /Users/foo/Desktop/Game/src/bar, however, I don't want the code to break through standard movement of files.

I also don't run directly in VSCode, I run my Makefile in terminal.

Is this a VSCode launch.json problem or something else? I have not created or edited a settings or launch file.

Makefile

```
CC = g++
# -g                            debug
# -Wall                         compiler warnings
# -mmacosx-version-min=12.0     deal with it macos error
# -fdiagnostics-color           colored debug
CFLAGS = -fdiagnostics-color=always -mmacosx-version-min=12.0 -g -Wall
CFLAGS += -std=c++17 -lglfw -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -lvulkan
S = shaders/

TARGET = Game

.PHONY: all clean shades

.SILENT:
# other files go before -o
all: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp -o $(TARGET)

clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
    $(RM) -r $(TARGET).dSYM

shades:
    glslc $(S)shader.vert -o $(S)vert.spv
    glslc $(S)shader.frag -o $(S)frag.spv
```

**Edit:** Side note question wasn’t understandable, here’s a new one:

Godot has a [user:// file system starter](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/filesystem.html) that auto links to (windows: %APPDATA%/Program Files, Mac: /System/Application Support, etc). Is there a c++ library that can do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

> when I run the executable, the working directory auto-defaults to /Users/foo, even though my file is in /Users/foo/Desktop/Game/src

You can't rely on the working directory being any particular value at runtime.  If you want to access files that are relative to your program's installation folder, then you need to retrieve your program's current location at runtime (for instance, on Windows, you can use `GetModuleFileName(NULL)`), and then manipulate that path as needed (drop/change the file name, append subfolders, etc).

> how do I locate the program files directory in c++?

Ask the OS.  For instance, on Windows, use `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_ProgramFiles)`.

> Is there a library to handle default writable file locations in c++?

Not one that is built-in to the C++ standard library, no.

Comment: How would I retrieve the program location? Standard things that rely on working directory don't work, like ./ and ../ .

Comment: @eap314 "*How would I retrieve the program location?*" - on Windows, you can use `GetModuleFileName(NULL)` and then strip off the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Two options, one while debugging, one "good" solution.

While debugging (if you don't want the "good" solution) you can get the path to your source file by including `__FILENAME__` and the chdir to whatever relative directory you want to go from there. *Note:* This is not suitable for releasing your program to others.

```
   std::string mysourcefile(__FILENAME__);
   _chdir(mysourcefile+"/../testdir");
```

This is a useful little trick during debugging.

---

But for the good option you can use boost::dll::program_location();

```
   boost::filesystem::path path_to_exe=boost::dll::program_location();
```

This will give you the full name and path of the executable in a portable way. From there you can use `boost::filesystem::path::parent` and similar methods to get the path (without the name of the executable) and change directories.